# Jquery event when user makes selection in dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down list.
In Jquery what is the event I would use when the user makes a selection.

The id of the dropdown is drp1

I tried the following but did not work:

```
$("#ddrp1").SelectChanged(SelectionItem);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event:

```
$("#ddrp1").change(function() {
    // Pure JS
    var selectedVal = this.value;
    var selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;

    // jQuery
    var selectedVal = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    var selectedText = $(this).find(':selected').text();
});
```

In jQuery 1.7, you can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#ddrp1").on("change", function() {
    // Pure JS
    var selectedVal = this.value;
    var selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;

    // jQuery
    var selectedVal = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    var selectedText = $(this).find(':selected').text();
}​​​​);​
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/LwwFL/) using `on()`

Comment: how do I get the text. Value in my case returns 5. Thakns

Comment: This works every time the option is _changed._ If someone uses the keyboard to move down a list in a dropdown, it will fire every single time. I need it to only fire once when the user has actually selected an option. Is there a way to detect if an option is actually selected when the user clicks on an option, hits enter on an option or tabs away after moving onto an option?

Comment: @pbarney when a select has focus and allows users to use the keyboard to switch between options, the selected option IS changing. There's no way around this functionality. There is no concept of "selecting" an option when using the keyboard, unless the user 1) first clicks on the dropdown to open it and then uses the keyboard to select & presses enter, or 2) when the select has focus they press the space bar to open it, then use the keyboard to select the desired option and press enter. The issue you're describing is simply select input focus + keyboard. That will always fire the change event.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is `onchange` event which can be written as

```
 $("#ddrp1").change (function () { 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `change` event handler.

```
$("#ddrp1").change(function(){
    //selection changed
    alert(this.value);//this will give the selected option's value
    alert($(this).find(':selected').text());//this will give the selected option's text
});
```

Alternative way to bind `change` event handler is.

```
$("#ddrp1").bind('change', function(){

});
```

Comment: How do you get the text, value returns 5 in my case.

Comment: To get the text of the selected option use `$(this).find(':selected').text()` where this is the dropdown element.

Comment: Thanks @ShankarSangoli

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `change()`.

jQuery change event occurs when the value of an element is changed.

This event is limited to `input` elements, `textarea` boxes and `select` elements.

```
$("#ddrp1").change (function () { 

     var getText = $(this).find(':selected').text();
     alert (getText); // show the text value of the selected element ...

 });
```